# Laravel + React

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs, laravel-5

I'm starting work on a large property listings website using react and laravel. Which of these two options would you advise and why?

**Option 1:** Use laravel react presets then have all your react components in a subfolder in your resources folder.

**Option 2:** Build the reactjs front-end completely outside laravel. Then build APIs with laravel that the react project will consume.

Comment: option 2 of course

Comment: obviously Option 2

Answer (score 2):

I am currently developing my 3rd Laravel-React project. So I can advice my way of doing things:

- I have a frontend named subfolder where i create my react app create-react-app .
- I use Laravel Passport for authentication. (I will use Laravel Sanctum on my next project)
- I use api controllers to communicate with Laravel.
- It is not essential but I also use Laravel Nova(It is not free but I think it is worth the money you pay) for backend administration and Laravel Telescope for monitoring my queries etc.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use the first option half the time when I am building Node applications but I will advice you use the second option as it makes for a more maintainable and cleaner project structure

Answer (score 1):

My opinion option 2 is better. Just there is some trouble more than option 1. That post or path request, cause your project run on different port. So, you need handle cross domain on develop stage. (No need cross domain when you run build and add your bundle to laravel project). But I think, Build the reactjs front-end completely outside laravel is more convenient, and clearly

Answer (score 1):

Instead React is a front library you can use it a Replacement of jQuery thats how i learned React JS.

**Eg:**

***Option 1*** : use Laravel Authentication and blade views and
Inside Blade views try to implement React for CRUD operation or form submit. Use CDN react links to get the dependencies. (Easy way of implementing a react functionality) - I prefer this to implement faster and easier

***Option 2*** : you can create a whole react application using `create-react-app` : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#creating-an-app

But for both options we need a Laravel REST API's to Manipulate the data's

Comment: Finally something that I was searching for. Although its an old post now, does this hold good with Laravel 10? Like I pass all my data in a variable to the blade and use react components inside blade is what you refer to?

Comment: Yes, Correct...